# How to return a copy of a value from an object in a vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Importantly, are not passing a whole object back in the getter. Need are passing copie of the object "singleMetricNamesMap" value it's a name for  metric were id is property. This is very important because if you pass back an object from the store, then anyone can mutate the store directly by changing the object. This whole class of bugs can be avoided by preferring getters which return primitive types

Here I watch of the metrics that change, and if the condition works, I pass the metric objects to store mutations

```js
watch: {
        metric() {
            if (this.metric) {
                this.setSingleMetricNamesMap({
                    id: this.metric.id,
                    name: this.metric.name })
            }
        }
    },
```

state:

```js
singleMetricNamesMap: {}
```

state getter were i try to return the metric name by id which I pass from the component

```js
singleMetricNamesMap: state => id => state.singleMetricNamesMap[id]
```

state mutations were i write metric objects into the state

```js
setSingleMetricNamesMap: (state, val) => {
            state.singleMetricNamesMap[val.id] = val.name
        },
```

The component where I pass the metric id to state getter and try to return a copy of the object (store.singleMetricNamesMap) value by id. But after reloading the page, I get undefined on the property of the object, that is, on id, and the names for the metrics appear only after the metric component is changed (for example, edited). Please tell me if I correctly return a copy of the value from the store.singleMetricNamesMap object and how to display metric names immediately when the component loads

```js
<z-dash-tile-config-option
            label="Metric"
            :value="singleMetricNamesMap(value.metricId)"
        >
```

Comment: Replace `state.singleMetricNamesMap[val.id] = val.name` with `Vue.set(state.singleMetricNamesMap,val.id,val.name)`

Comment: Also, use an `immediate` watcher.

Comment: @StevenSpungin ok, thanks i will try